Allocated memory in heap by a function() is acting like stack memory
I have been searching for 2 days , I read similar posts but still can`t grasp what is
happening in my heap memory.
I want to make a program that takes a password from cmd arguments of the program      (char* argv[]), allocate the input to a (char* buffer) in heap and compare it to a hardcoded (char* password).
I have the pointer (char* buffer) declared in main().
Function AllocateBuffer() takes the pointer as parameter and allocates memory to it with
malloc.
I do not return the address of the pointer back thinking that the pointer is declared in main() and the memory malloced through AllocateBuffer() is on the heap so I must free() it
myself.
I do a check and fill the malloced memory in AllocateBuffer() with As and all is good.
When I go to store what I really want using another function StoreBuffer() I check the pointer block(char* buffer) again.
It is gone with the wind like it was stack memory!!!
Why?
My pointer char* buffer is in main() its memory in the heap, this makes no sense.
I am new to C and all I hear and read is that pointers are ALWAYS passed by reference.
What is the problem here?
What am I missing?
Thank you in advance and I am sry for the long post.
My input is "atrocity32 super secret" below there are my input and results in cmd.
My code:
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>



int GetBufferLength(int args_num, char* argsv[])
{
    unsigned int blen = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < args_num; i++)
    {
        blen += strlen(argsv[i]) + 1; 
    }
    printf("BufferLength is :%u\n", blen);
    return blen;
}


int AllocateBuffer(char* bufferName, int bufferLen)
{
    bufferName = malloc(sizeof(char) * bufferLen);
    if (bufferName != NULL)
    {

        printf("buffer Allocation Ok !!!\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < bufferLen; i++)
        {
            if (i == bufferLen - 1)
            {
                *(bufferName + i) = '\0';
                printf("End address that buffer points to in Heap : %p\n", (bufferName + i));
                printf("*(bufferName+%d) : %c\n", i, *(bufferName + i));
                break;
            }
            *(bufferName + i) = 'A';
            printf("*(bufferName+%d) : %c\n", i, *(bufferName + i));
        }
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Could not allocate buffer!!!\n");
        return 0;
    }
}

//Here I just make a buffer check, the actual code has been ommited for better  
//understanding.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void StoreBuffer(char* bufferName, int buffer_length, const char* argsv[], int argsc)
{
    printf("%s", bufferName);
}



//From here on I just included the functions to see my program flow no need to read them if     
//you don`t feel like it, just go to main().
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void CompareBuffer(char* bufferName, char* string)
{
    printf("CompareBuffer : %s", bufferName);
    if (strcmp(bufferName, string) == 0)
    {
        printf("Password correct.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Password NOT correct.\n");
    }
}




DeallocBuffer(char* bufferName)
{
    free(bufferName);
    bufferName = NULL;
}




//main()
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* password = "super secret";
    int bufferlength = GetBufferLength(argc, argv);


    char* buffer = NULL; 

    if (AllocateBuffer(buffer, bufferlength))
    {     
          
          //Here is the point of failure Storebuffer(), buffer is nul, see CMD input/output below
          --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          StoreBuffer(buffer, bufferlength, argv, argc);
        
        
         //CompareBuffer(buffer, password);
         //DeallocBuffer(buffer);
    }


    return 0;
}

My input and results in CMD:
C:\Users\Strakizzz\Desktop\C\experiment\experiment\atrocity\bin>atrocity32.exe super secret
BufferLength is :13
buffer Allocation Ok !!!
*(bufferName+0) : A
*(bufferName+1) : A
*(bufferName+2) : A
*(bufferName+3) : A
*(bufferName+4) : A
*(bufferName+5) : A
*(bufferName+6) : A
*(bufferName+7) : A
*(bufferName+8) : A
*(bufferName+9) : A
*(bufferName+10) : A
*(bufferName+11) : A
End address that buffer points to in Heap : 00AF6C84
*(bufferName+12) :
(null)


Assigning to bufferName in allocateBuffer() only assigns that local variable, it doesn't assign the variable in main(). It would be best to return the pointer.

It seems a bit overkill, when you could do it in one line with if(argc > 1 && strcmp(argv[1], password) == 0) puts ("Success!");

@Barmar But pointers are passed by reference!!!And my pointer (char* buffer) is in main() not inside the function.

Pointers are passed as pointers.

@Sotiris Pointers are passed by value. You're thinking of arrays, which decay to a pointer to the first element when passed as arguments.

@ Weather Vane I did that function keeping in mind that i may would use more than 2 arguments  e.g. instead of "super secret" , "super secret password".

You can make one argument with myprog "super secret". Or you can forget about passing passwords as program arguments and use fgets().

If you want to pass a pointer by reference, you have to pass its address, just like any other variable: allocateBuffer(&bufferName, bufferLen)

Don't use *(bufferName + i), use the more idiomatic bufferName[i].

@ Barmar all I have ever read and watched is that pointers are the way C passes something by reference, in fact it is called pass by pointers to be exact.

What passwords contain spaces anyway? Is that one space or two (both will be lost when passed as program arguments). And suppose you enter a leading space? That ought to be refused.

@BarMar if i pass &buffer that is char**.When I go to malloc I want to malloc memory to the address buffer is pointing to.

And you do *bufferName = malloc(...). This is all explained in the linked question, have you read that?

@Sotiris Use int AllocateBuffer(char** bufferName, size_t bufferLen) {  *bufferName = malloc(bufferLen);...

But like I said above, you could avoid all this if you just have the function return the pointer. So you do char *buffer = allocateBuffer(bufferLen);

@Barmar Thank you for your answers, I need to think about it and read on that.

@chux - Reinstate Monica Thank you for your answers, I need to think about it and read on that.

You need to be careful to distinguish between objects and values.  char *p declares an object, identified by p in that scope, whose value is to be interpreted as a pointer to char.  The object is some kind of storage, possibly with an associated address.  The value is whatever is recorded in that storage.  When you pass an argument of any type to a function, that argument is evaluated to produce a value, and the value is passed.  The called function has storage of some kind for that value, which is distinct from anything accesible to the caller.

Passing pointers is no different.  If I call foo(p) then foo receives a pointer value, recorded in storage specific to that execution of foo, that can be used to access the same object, if any, that could be accessed via p in the scope where the function call appears.  But the storage identified by p in the caller is not accessible to foo.  If foo assigns a new value to its corresponding local variable, then that goes into its local object.  This is no different from passing ints or doubles.

Some people seem to have trouble grasping that pointer (objects) are entirely separate and independent from the objects, if any, to which their values point.  A double * is not a double in any way.  The term "pass by pointer" is almost as misleading as "pass by reference" for describing calls to functions that have parameters of pointer type.  When you pass a pointer to an object, you are not passing that object itself at all.  You are passing a pointer (value).
